# Showing that if $xf(x)=\log x$ for $x>0$, then $f^{(n)}(1)=(-1)^{n+1}n!\left(1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, induction

> Let $f(x)$ be a function satisfying $$xf(x)=\log x$$ for $x>0$. Show that $$f^{(n)}(1)=(-1)^{n+1}n!\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right),$$ where $f^{(n)}(x)$ denotes the $n$th derivative of the function $f$ evaluated at $x$.

I attempted plain differentiation of the function. But, that seemed to go the complex way. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint.* We know that
$$
(f\: g)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(f)^{(k)}(g)^{(n-k)}
$$ giving
$$
\left(\frac{1}{x} \times \ln x\right)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)^{(k)}(\ln x)^{(n-k)}
$$ then use
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)^{(k)}&=(-1)^k\frac{k!}{x^{k+1}}\\\\
(\ln x)^{(n-k)}&=\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)^{(n-k-1)}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First, write out the first few derivatives of each side of $$x f(x) = \log x$$ (rather than the derivatives of $f(x) = \frac{\log x}{x}$), identify the patterns of the derivatives, and prove that they are correct (using, say, induction).

Comment: Then induction part is giving me troubles...how would I know what will be the function after the $n-1$-th differentiation. I would have to differentiate again and then put the value...would you please tell me?

Comment: Don't worry about the $n$th derivative of the two sides before computing the first few derivatives manually, the patterns become apparent after just a few steps.